# How to clear a region in python3 Pillow

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

How to clear a region with `ImageDraw` in python3 Pillow?

```
im = Image.new('RGBA', (1200, 400), (0, 0, 0, 0))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)

...

draw.rectangle((100, 100, 300, 150), fill=(0, 0, 0, 0))
draw.text((100, 100), 'Hello World!', font=font, fill=(0, 0, 255, 255))
canvas.write(im.tobytes())
```

My idea was to draw a rectangle with `fill=(0, 0, 0, 0)` but this rectangle gets blended to the image changing no pixels due to the `alpha` component is `0`.

I am updating an image 60 times per sec and I cannot afford to redraw the entire image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bug was somewhere else in my code.

To clear a region just call

```
draw.rectangle((100, 100, 300, 150), fill=(0, 0, 0, 0))
```

The region `(100, 100, 300, 150)` will be filled with the color given in the `fill` parameter. The rectangle is not blended at all in this case.